# Does scoped CSS affect on build performance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We use massive bunch of components in our products with Vue 2 (migrating on 3rd version) and Nuxt SSR. Could we improve our project performance with removing scoped block of styles (how much)?

Comment: nope, but migrating to vue3 will

Answer (score 2):

Scoped CSS can have some performance impact: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

So you could improve it if you can achieve the styling without the CSS scoping (even tho, depending of the solution replacing it, that may be more heavy overall).

How much is hard to answer here because it depends of your app and if you have some performance benchmarks already.

Migrating to Vue3 will bring quite some performance tho. But as everything, it all depends on the current bottlenecks. If you have a Google UTM tag importing à whole 3rd party chat library, removing the scoped styles will only have a minor impact.

So yeah, to broad of a question with too much variables to give a concrete answer.